# Deno import maps and lock file

Tags: deno

As far as I know, Deno lock files can only be created when using a TypeScript (or JavaScript) file with all the imports on it — usually from a `deps.ts` file.

I would like to be able to use (the unstable yet) *import maps* and also generate that lock file based on it.

Is it possible to generate that lock file from an `import_map.json` file? If it's not possible, is there any other way to use a `deps.ts` file, for instance, an be able to map the dependencies in order to import them without using (the infamous) `./..` everywhere?

Moreover, looks like using the `paths` feature on a `tsconfig.json` file wouldn't do since I don't have any idea how to refer to any module on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot directly generate a lock file based on an import map yet. But you can pass the entry file of your program along with the import map to generate a lock file.

Here's an example.

`log.ts`:

```js
import { green } from "colors";
console.log(`Status: ${green("OK")}`);
```

`deps.json` (import map):

```json
{
  "imports": {
    "colors": "https://deno.land/std@0.88.0/fmt/colors.ts"
  }
}
```

Now run the following command to generate a lock file.

```sh
deno cache --import-map=deps.json --unstable --lock=lock.json --lock-write log.ts
```

The content of `lock.json` might look like below.

```json
{
  "https://deno.land/std@0.88.0/fmt/colors.ts": "db22b314a2ae9430ae7460ce005e0a7130e23ae1c999157e3bb77cf55800f7e4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Another solution](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/13446) that works very closely or better since it actually scans through all the dependencies the project uses is to run: `deno test --no-run --import-map import-map.json --lock lock.json --lock-write`.

> Note that this only works for modules that have test coverage.